# For the A* algorithm, is this a decent heuristic function? Why or why not?

Tags: algorithm, graph-algorithm

15 - Puzzle Problem explained : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/15_puzzle

In order to solve the 15-puzzle problem, I have written a heuristic function to decide which state is best to access. So, I wrote a heuristic function called update fgh, for every node it increases g by 1, and h increases relative to the distance of each node from the goal state.

The 15 puzzle problem is a random array of 15 tiles that are each numbered 1-15 that are scattered in random order on a 4 x 4 box with a blank tile added as well.

To solve the 15 puzzle, you have to move the blank tile in place of a tile to its left to its right , bottom or top.

When each number is in order from 1-15 and the blank tile at the end, the 15 puzzle problem is solved.

The variables in my code are the following

***///[variables in pnode]///***

**N - represents 4 tiles in the precompiler to make code more portable and for security reasons of course.**

**NxN - represents 4 arrays of 4 tiles in the precompiler to make code more portable and for security reasons of course.**

**pnode - The puzzle node that includes the state the puzzle is in.**

**f- the f variable of the heuristic.**

**g- the g variable of the heuristic.**

**h - the h variable of the heuristic.**

**zero_column && zero row - the variables representing the zero tile in p-node**

***next and *parent - The child and parent nodes of puzzle node, each pnode holds a next with the zero column shifted either up, down, left or right, with the node up down left or right chosen provided the heuristic is cheapest**

**///[global variables]///**

**int goal_rows[NxN]; - The goal rows that hold an array of 16 nodes.**

**int goal_columns[NxN]; - The goal columns that hold an array of 16 nodes**

**struct node *start,*goal; - The starting node which is initialized and selected by the user of the program using argv[] to choose numbers 1-15 in random order plus a blank node. and to create a goal node to compare the goal and initial node**

**struct node *open = NULL, *closed = NULL; - Two nodes with open and available nodes along with nodes that simply cannot be added or used and are therefore placed in closed to avoid contemplating them any further.**

**struct node *succ_nodes[4]; - Successful nodes a pointer that points to an array of 4 pnodes that are successful.**

```
update_fgh(struct node *pnode)
{
    pnode->f = g + h;
    for(i = 0; i < 16; i++)
        g++;
    for(j =0; j< 16; j++){
        //Goal is a global variable state.
        if(pnode->start[i] != goal[j])
            pnode->h++;
        else 
            continue; 
    }
    pnode->f = pnode->g+->h; 
}
```

Here is the code where the heuristic is being used:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define N 4
#define NxN (N*N)
#define TRUE 1
#define FALSE 0

struct node {
    int tiles[N][N];
    int f, g, h;
    short zero_row, zero_column;    /* location (row and colum) of blank tile 0 */
    struct node *next;
    struct node *parent;            /* used to trace back the solution */
};

int goal_rows[NxN];
int goal_columns[NxN];
struct node *start,*goal;
struct node *open = NULL, *closed = NULL;
struct node *succ_nodes[4];

void print_a_node(struct node *pnode) {
    int i,j;
    for (i=0;i<N;i++) {
        for (j=0;j<N;j++)
            printf("%2d ", pnode->tiles[i][j]);
        printf("\n");
    }
    printf("\n");
}

struct node *initialize(char **argv){
    int i,j,k,index, tile;
    struct node *pnode;

    pnode=(struct node *) malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    index = 1;
    for (j=0;j<N;j++)
        for (k=0;k<N;k++) {
            tile=atoi(argv[index++]);
            pnode->tiles[j][k]=tile;
            if(tile==0) {
                pnode->zero_row=j;
                pnode->zero_column=k;
            }
        }
    pnode->f=0;
    pnode->g=0;
    pnode->h=0;
    pnode->next=NULL;
    pnode->parent=NULL;
    start=pnode;
    printf("initial state\n");
    print_a_node(start);

    pnode=(struct node *) malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    goal_rows[0]=3;
    goal_columns[0]=3;

    for(index=1; index<NxN; index++){
        j=(index-1)/N;
        k=(index-1)%N;
        goal_rows[index]=j;
        goal_columns[index]=k;
        pnode->tiles[j][k]=index;
    }
    pnode->tiles[N-1][N-1]=0;         /* empty tile=0 */
    pnode->f=0;
    pnode->g=0;
    pnode->h=0;
    pnode->next=NULL;
    goal=pnode;
    printf("goal state\n");
    print_a_node(goal);

    return start;
}

/* merge unrepeated nodes into open list after filtering */
void merge_to_open() {
}

/*swap two tiles in a node*/
void swap(int row1,int column1,int row2,int column2, struct node * pnode){
    int tile = pnode->tiles[row1][coulmn1];
    pnode->tiles[row1][column1]=pnode->tiles[row2][column2];
    pnode->tiles[row2][column2]=tile;
}

/*update the f,g,h function values for a node */
update_fgh(struct node *pnode)
{
    pnode->f = g + h;
    for(i = 0; i < 16; i++)
        g++;
    for(j =0; j< 16; j++){
        //Goal is a global variable state.
        if(pnode->start[i] != goal[j])
            pnode->h++;
        else 
            continue; 
    }
    pnode->f = pnode->g+->h; 
}

/* 0 goes down by a row */
void move_down(struct node * pnode){
    swap(pnode->zero_row, pnode->zero_column, pnode->zero_row+1, pnode->zero_column, pnode);
    pnode->zero_row++;
}

/* 0 goes right by a column */
void move_right(struct node * pnode){
    swap(pnode->zero_row, pnode->zero_column, pnode->zero_row, pnode->zero_column+1, pnode);
    pnode->zero_column++;
}

/* 0 goes up by a row */
void move_up(struct node * pnode){
    swap(pnode->zero_row, pnode->zero_column, pnode->zero_row-1, pnode->zero_column, pnode);
    pnode->zero_row--;
}

/* 0 goes left by a column */
void move_left(struct node * pnode){
    swap(pnode->zero_row, pnode->zero_column, pnode->zero_row, pnode->zero_column-1, pnode);
    pnode->zero_column--;
}

/* expand a node, get its children nodes, and organize the children nodes using
 * array succ_nodes.
 */
void expand(struct node *selected) {
}

int nodes_same(struct node *a,struct node *b) {
    int flg=FALSE;
    if (memcmp(a->tiles, b->tiles, sizeof(int)*NxN) == 0)
        flg=TRUE;
    return flg;
}

/* Filtering. Some nodes in succ_nodes may already be included in either open
 * or closed list. Remove them. It is important to reduce execution time.
 * This function checks the (i)th node in succ_nodes array. You must call this
 & function in a loop to check all the nodes in succ_nodes.
 */
void filter(int i, struct node *pnode_list){
    if(nodes_same(*pnode_list, succ_nodes[i]) == TRUE)
    pnode_list = pnode_list->next; 
}


int main(int argc,char **argv) {
    int iter,cnt;
    struct node *copen, *cp, *solution_path;
    int ret, i, pathlen=0, index[N-1];

    solution_path=NULL;
    start=initialize(argv); /* init initial and goal states */
    open=start;

    iter=0;
    while (open!=NULL) {    /* Termination cond with a solution is tested in expand. */
        copen=open;
        open=open->next;  /* get the first node from open to expand */
        if(nodes_same(copen,goal)){ /* goal is found */
            do{ /* trace back and add the nodes on the path to a list */
                copen->next=solution_path;
                solution_path=copen;
                copen=copen->parent;
                pathlen++;
            } while(copen!=NULL);
            printf("Path (lengh=%d):\n", pathlen);
            copen=solution_path;
            ... /* print out the nodes on the list */
            break;
        }
        expand(copen);       /* Find new successors */
        for(i=0;i<4;i++){
            filter(i,open);
            filter(i,closed);
        }
        merge_to_open(); /* New open list */
        copen->next=closed;
        closed=copen;       /* New closed */
        /* print out something so that you know your
         * program is still making progress
         */
        iter++;
        if(iter %1000 == 0)
            printf("iter %d\n", iter);
    }
    return 0;
} /* end of main */
```

Comment: Could you briefly explain (or link) what the 15-puzzle problem is and what your variables are?

Comment: Please show how you use that function. It looks like your heuristic makes sense. The calculation of `g`, however, looks a bit suspicious.

Comment: This code doesn't use the function anywhere.

Comment: @Neil I both linked and explained the 15 puzzle problem and what the variables are supposed to do.

Comment: You are trying to count the number of misplaced tiles? Adding a constant to `g` is not going to get you anywhere, because, like energy, the relative differences are what's important.

Comment: Well yes, that's what h is for. If for example, I have let's say 15 in position 3. The program counts up up up until it see's where 3 is and adds that to the 'h' of the current state. It does this not just for position 3 but every mismatched position. g is just added by default. If it exists, then it adds 1.

Comment: I think ignoring one makes it https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dijkstra%27s_algorithm, which is simpler, but I don't think that's what you want.

Comment: Currently, your function just increments `g` by `16`, no matter what. It should be the number of moves that you made. If your version is correct depends on how you use the function - that's why I asked for it. But it is still not used anywhere in the code.